# Why aren't Onesignal notifications causing the app to open?

Tags: php, web-applications, push-notification, onesignal

I am using my web app to create notifications in onesignal through the API.

Its working ok and notifications are being received, however when the user clicks on the push notification it does not open the app, just goes to phone home screen.

Can anyone see an error in my code?  all in PHP.

```
<?PHP
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'testing push message to all active users'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "my app id ",
        'included_segments' => array('Active Users'),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic my rest APIkey'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode( $return);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");  ?>
```